# Object disappears after updating buffer

Tags: opengl, 3d, rendering, lwjgl

I tried to implement triangle subdivision algorithm and I encountered that if I'm updating buffers with bigger arrays geometry disappears.  As you can see I'm using `glBufferData()` to update buffers. It works if I'm updating buffers with same size (or smaller) arrays. It should work but it's not.

```
glGetString(GL_VERSION) -> 3.1.0 - Build 9.17.10.3517
glGetString(GL_VENDOR) -> Intel
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY) -> DONE
glEnableClientState(GL_INDEX_ARRAY) -> DONE
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE) -> DONE
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) -> DONE
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE) -> DONE
glCullFace(Off) -> DONE
glDepthFunc(LessOrEqual) -> DONE
glBindBuffer(VertexArray, -1) -> DONE
glBindBuffer(ElementArray, -1) -> DONE
glBindTexture(Texture2D, -1) -> DONE
glActiveTexture(0) -> DONE
glClientActiveTexture(0) -> DONE
glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600) -> DONE

// Initializing
glGenBuffers() -> 1
glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 1) -> DONE
glBufferData(VertexArray, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=9 cap=9], Static) -> DONE
glGenBuffers() -> 2
glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 2) -> DONE
glBufferData(VertexArray, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=6 cap=6], Static) -> DONE
glGenBuffers() -> 3
glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 3) -> DONE
glBufferData(VertexArray, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=9 cap=9], Static) -> DONE
glGenBuffers() -> 4
glBindBuffer(ElementArray, 4) -> DONE
glBufferData(ElementArray, java.nio.DirectIntBufferU[pos=0 lim=3 cap=3], Static) -> DONE

glClear(ColorAndDepth) -> DONE
glLoadIdentity() -> DONE
glMatrixMode(Projection) -> DONE
glLoadIdentity() -> DONE
gluPerspective(60.0, 1.3333334, 0.001, 999999.0) -> DONE
glMatrixMode(ModelView) -> DONE
glBindBuffer(VertexArray, -1) -> DONE
glBindBuffer(ElementArray, -1) -> DONE

glPushMatrix() -> DONE
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) -> DONE
    glScalef(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) -> DONE
    glMultMatrix(java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=16 cap=16]) -> DONE

    glPolygonMode(FrontAndBack, Line) -> DONE
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0) -> DONE
    glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 1) -> DONE
    glVertexPointer(3, Float, 0, 0) -> DONE
    glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 3) -> DONE
    glNormalPointer(Float, 0, 0) -> DONE
    glBindBuffer(ElementArray, 4) -> DONE
    glDrawElements(Triangles, 3, UnsignedInt, 0) -> DONE
glPopMatrix() -> DONE
// Cycle end

// Updating
glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 1) -> DONE
glBufferData(VertexArray, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=18 cap=18], Static) -> DONE
glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 2) -> DONE
glBufferData(VertexArray, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=12 cap=12], Static) -> DONE
glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 3) -> DONE
glBufferData(VertexArray, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=18 cap=18], Static) -> DONE
glBufferData(ElementArray, java.nio.DirectIntBufferU[pos=0 lim=6 cap=6], Static) -> DONE

glClear(ColorAndDepth) -> DONE
glLoadIdentity() -> DONE
glMatrixMode(Projection) -> DONE
glLoadIdentity() -> DONE
gluPerspective(60.0, 1.3333334, 0.001, 999999.0) -> DONE
glMatrixMode(ModelView) -> DONE
glPolygonMode(FrontAndBack, Fill) -> DONE
glBindBuffer(VertexArray, -1) -> DONE
glBindBuffer(ElementArray, -1) -> DONE

glPushMatrix() -> DONE
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) -> DONE
    glScalef(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) -> DONE
    glMultMatrix(java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=16 cap=16]) -> DONE

    glPolygonMode(FrontAndBack, Line) -> DONE
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0) -> DONE
    glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 1) -> DONE
    glVertexPointer(3, Float, 0, 0) -> DONE
    glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 3) -> DONE
    glNormalPointer(Float, 0, 0) -> DONE
    glBindBuffer(ElementArray, 4) -> DONE
    glDrawElements(Triangles, 6, UnsignedInt, 0) -> DONE
glPopMatrix() -> DONE
```

0 - This is result I want. It works when setted with new buffers.
1 - This is a source triangle.

[image: iamge]

Answer (score 0):

Okay! I finally found the source of my problem. After subdividing proccess all indices turned into 0. Thanks! And don't forget to check actual data you sending!